# Is it correct to say "there is no contact between the cities" to mean you can't get travel between the cities?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

Could you tell me if it is correct to say *there is no contact between the cities* to mean you can't get travel between the cities? For example:

> At the moment **there is no contact between the cities**: the road is flooded.

If it doesn't sound natural, what are natural ways to say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"No contact" would seem to suggest that the phone lines are down too.

I think I'd phrase it as "There is no route between the cities".  Or "The cities are cut off from each other."

<sub>Or the famous headline "Fog in English Channel. Continent cut off"</sub>